# Why is this access of base class data members deemed to be type punning (in optimized builds)?

Tags: c++, optimization, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I've got something along the lines of:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Core
{
  void* mData{};
  size_t mCount{};
};

template <typename T>
struct Actual: protected Core
{
  Actual() = default;

  Actual(Actual<T> const& other) = delete;
  Actual<T>& operator=(Actual<T> const& other) = delete;

  Actual(Actual<T>&& other):
    Core{ other.mData, other.mCount }
  {
    other.mData = nullptr;
    other.mCount = 0;
  }

  Actual<T>& operator=(Actual<T>&& other)
  {
    Actual<T> tmp(std::move(other));
    std::swap(mData, tmp.mData);    // with -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror: "error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]"
    mCount = tmp.mCount;            // ditto
    return *this;
  }      

  ~Actual() { /* delete[] mData as array of T, if it was created */ }

  // rest of the API incl. allocating that array of T into mData, not relevant
};

int main() {
  Actual<int> a;
  Actual<int> b;
  b = std::move(a);
}
```

This compiles fine *until* optimizations are requested (`-O2` and above).

The question is simply, why does the compiler (GCC 9.3.0) think that this is type punning / a violation of strict aliasing rule, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please try to provide a proper [mcve] which only describes or replicates the problem you're asking about, without any other irrelevant (but distracting) problems. Also, if you get compiler message please copy-paste them in full and complete, and add comments on the lines where you get them.

Comment: Did the compiler raise any warning or error? If so, please provide the message. In general I have no idea what the question is. BTW: Why you don't have all the constructors/operators related to `core` not in `core`? You access base class members as they were direct members which is bad design!

Comment: Why do you think GCC thinks this is type punning?

Comment: @PatrickParker To zero the members by default?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but is `void* mData{};` the same as `void* mData = 0;` ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I've updated example now with diagnostic that I get, and it's from GCC.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes.

Comment: On godbolt, it reproduces with gcc-9.3 but not 9.4 (and 10.1 but not 10.2), so a compiler bug seems likely.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it repros on wandbox.org just fine. it's fine on the next available version, 10.1.0.

Comment: You might want to use `Actual(Actual&& other) : Core{ std::exchange(other.mData, nullptr), std::exchange(other.mCount, 0) } {}`.  I'm not sure why the code is using `Actual<T>` where it could just use `Actual` because in context the `<T>` is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a GCC bug. GCC 9.4 and newer don't diagnose this.

If you rewrite `operator=` like this, it stops complaining, and this form is also shorter.

```
Actual<T>& operator=(Actual<T> other)
{
    std::swap(mData, other.mData);
    std::swap(mCount, other.mCount); // I like this more than `mCount = tmp.mCount;`.
    return *this;
}
```

For it to work, you have to remove `Actual<T>& operator=(Actual<T> const& other) = delete;`, and you might as well remove `Actual(Actual<T> const& other) = delete;`.

You also should add `noexcept` to the move constructor and to this assignment operator, lest standard containers (when resized) decide to copy instances of your class instead of moving them.

Comment: Thank you; this seems to work. First time I'm seeing this sort of assignment though -- would you mind detailing why not the [regular] move assignment, taking an rvalue reference? (noexcept fair enough btw.)

Comment: @zyndor This is a combined copy/move assignment, it can act as a copy assignment if and only if you have a copy ctor, and/or as a move assignment if you have a move ctor. I prefer it just because it's less typing, but otherwise it should be mostly equivalent to what you had.

Comment: This form does the right thing for most classes (only exception I know is classes that update some external pointer to themselves when moved). It's also completely exception-safe. It may be a bit slower than the conventional `operator=` in rare cases.